# Android video overlay for Periscope

Tags: android, camera, png, overlay, root

I need to make broadcast periscope with png logo. Could I make it through the Root and acting on camera android? 
applying it as a watermark on any image from the camera.
thank you

Comment: You don't need root to send live video recorded from your Android camera. Check libstreaming project on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you but, Maybe I said it is not clear. I need a logo overlay on the image obtained from the camera. Always. Regardless of the program. I need to broadcast stream in the program Periscope with logo overlay.
The program refers to the camera - the camera, transferring image puts watermark - and with it transmits the stream in the program Periscope.

Comment: You mean that you want to use the Periscope app unchanged, but do something to the device, so that Periscope receives a different image? I thought you wanted to build a broadcasting app compatible with Periscope

Comment: right. is needed as to the substitution of  transmitted images from the camera. it is somehow possible to realize through the camera api.

Comment: Depends on how Periscope communicates with camera. Also, on device and ROM. Which device do you <strike>ab</strike>use this way?